# Converting from Python-Polars to Rust-Polars

Tags: rust, python-polars, rust-polars

I have the following working Python polars code. I am learning Rust and am interested in converting Python to Rust.

```
df = df.with_columns(pl.concat([pl.col(base).slice(0, period).rolling_mean(period), pl.col(base).slice(period,None)]).alias('con'))
```

How to convert the same in Rust? It might be very trivial, still not sure where I am going wrong.

```
let rolling_options = RollingOptions {
        window_size : Duration::parse(duration_str.as_str()),
        ..Default::default()
    };
let a = col(base).slice(0,period).rolling_mean(rolling_options);
let b = col(base).slice(period,lit(Null {}));

let temp_df = df.with_column(concat([a, b], UnionArgs::default()));
```

I keep getting the following error

> mismatched types
> expected enum `Expr`
> found enum `Result<LazyFrame, PolarsError>`

When i checked the data types of **a** and **b**, to my surprise they are **LazyFrame** and not **Expr**

[rolling_mean](https://docs.rs/polars/latest/polars/prelude/enum.Expr.html#method.rolling_mean) as per the document returns **Expr** and so does [slice](https://docs.rs/polars/latest/polars/prelude/enum.Expr.html#method.slice). Not sure what I am missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working code.

```
let duration_str = format!("{}{}",usize::try_from(period).unwrap().to_string().as_str(),"i");

let rolling_options = RollingOptions {
    window_size : Duration::parse(duration_str.as_str()),
    min_periods : usize::try_from(period).unwrap(),
    ..Default::default()
};

let lf = df.with_column(concat_expr([col(base).slice(0,period).rolling_mean(rolling_options), 
    col(base).slice(period,lit(Null {}))], false)?.alias("con"));
```

Answer (score 4):

The result datatype you are getting is an enum meant to represent whether the operation was successful (returns a lazyFrame) or it failed (returns polarserror).

There are a bunch of ways to unwrap (pattern match) an enum, but below are my favorite

`foo.unwrap()` or `foo?` if you are using error propagation

This link should cover the different ways to handle errors/results in rust:
https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch09-02-recoverable-errors-with-result.html

Comment: Hi Dmitriy_I, Thanks for taking the time to answer the question. I understand the question might have been better, but the answer i was looking for is not the above one. I have got it working after going through the source code of polars.
In the above example, i am using `concat` which takes 2 LazyFrames but i should be using `concat_expr` instead in case of rust.